# Letter spacing for multiple words with memoir?

Tags: memoir, letterspacing

I got letter spacing working but it doesn't work with spaces? How do I get it to recognize spaces?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\Large\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=100}{Three separate words}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that `\Large` doesn't take an argument.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont=TeX Gyre Termes,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]

\NewDocumentCommand{\spacedscshape}{}{%
  \scshape
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{5\fontdimen2\font plus 5\fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen3\font}%
  \addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=50}%
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textspacedsc}{\spacedscshape}

\begin{document}

\textspacedsc{Three separate words}

{\Large\spacedscshape Three separate words}

\end{document}
```

I used small caps in order to avoid being charged of sheep stealing.

[image]

Comment: An excellent answer.